# Hide created file in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, mobile-development

Using UWP I am creating a file in the Documents folder and after creation I am trying to hide the file but the file was not getting hidden. Below is the sample code I used to hide.

```
     var localsetting = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
     var versionfile = await localsetting.CreateFileAsync("TEST.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
     await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(versionfile, "TEst Content2");
     System.IO.File.SetAttributes(versionfile.Path, System.IO.FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

Is it possible to hide the file?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code. The problem is you can't set hidden attribute for the file in `DocumentsLibrary` even if the you has explicitly given access to the folder. For uwp apps the available file attributes are listed in the [`Windows.Storage.FileAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.FileAttributes) enum, as you can see the `Hidden` attribute is not included.

Windows Store apps run sandboxed and have very limited access to the file system. For the most part, they can directly access only their install folder and their application data folder. Access to other locations is available only through a broker process. It is by design. So you might be able to hidden file where created in the [`LocalFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder).

```
var Local = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var versionfile = await localsetting.CreateFileAsync("TEST.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(versionfile, "TEst Content2");
System.IO.File.SetAttributes(versionfile.Path, System.IO.FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

However, we do not recommend that you hidden file in your uwp application. Because if you have hidden the file and then you created a same name file by following code. It will throw exception.

```
localsetting.CreateFileAsync("TEST.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```